# The named parameter 'xxx' isn't defined

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

So im getting this error that's going all throughout my project, however I can't seem to find anything on it anywhere else

[image]
Also you can see here it goes all throughout my project.

[image]

it's also worth mentioning that I have ran "flutter clean" "flutter pub get" and that didn't seem to fix anything

thank you

Comment: You should restart your IDE

Comment: Does this  file import material.dart ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the command palette by pressing `cmd+shift+p`. Search for dart restart analysis server. Try to restart it and if it didn't work too try to restart your computer.

[image: Restart Dart Analysis Server]

Comment: I tried this and also restarting my IDE, didn't work :/

Comment: Did you try to restart your computer?

Comment: I did yeah, I've done this, restarted IDE, uninstalled Dart and flutter, reinstalled dart and flutter, flutter upgrade, flutter clean cache

Comment: If you have tried all of these. I would suggest that you run the project on another computer just to investigate the issue. Please run it on another computer if you can to see if it works.